# window.location.replace not working if the same page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to refresh page on Ajax success.

```
var lastId = "#" + id;
window.location.replace("/myurl" + lastId);
```

It is writing the correct URL to my browser but I don't see the changes made. If I refresh (F5) the page, I see the changes correctly because the ajax was correctly sended.

So I think that page won't force refresh if the url is the same.

In this example, I'm already on `http://mypage.com/myurl`, it is supossed to redirect me to `http://mypage.com/myurl#38174` for example, so my browser will focus the DOM element with `id="38174"`.

As I said, if I submit the ajax request, my url changes to `http://mypage.com/myurl#38174` and focus  `id="38174"` but I don't see the changes made to that element on my DB, if I hit F5, it focus the same element but with the changes correctly shown.

Why is this hapening?

I've also tried with `window.location.href` and `window.location` without success.

If I use `window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');` it's sending me to this website correctly...

So I think the problem is when replacing with the same url + some hashtag... maybe?

As I've said, in this case in particular we need to refresh after an AJAX request only if it's a success, yes, it sounds weird and counterproductive but it is needed.

Comment: Updating the fragment of a URL doesn't cause the page to reload - as you've seen. You would need to change the fragment, then call `window.location.reload()` manually, however this makes the point of making an AJAX request rather moot. The general idea is that you make the AJAX request, which updates your datastore and then passes back enough information for the UI to update itself.

Comment: Why are you forcing a reload for an ajax call? That seems like the opposite of what an ajax call is supposed to accomplish

Comment: Isn't the point of using Ajax is that you don't need to reload?

Comment: Yes, the point of ajax is that you don't need to reload, but in this case in particular we need to reload ONLY if everything went OK, because we're using AngularJS and we don't/can't replace HTML content with the retrieved data, because we are using static content with TWIG, long history, but we need to reload in this case in particular.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I will need to find another way then, because the fragment will always be the same...

Comment: You could add a nonce parameter - `window.location.replace("/myurl" + lastId + "?_=" + Date.now());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var lastId = "#" + id;
window.location.replace("/myurl" + lastId);
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: window.location.replace is not working for the local file path (eg: file:///C:/1.html)

Comment: That is probably a matter for a new question (with specifics, e.g. code; what the starting and new locations look like; and any errors from the browser development tools console).

Answer (score 0):

Updating a hash from the URL will not trigger a new pageload.

You'll need to listen to the hashchange event in javascript to initiate your ajax call, without the need for your page to refresh. This will give you a better user experience

If you use jQuery, you can use something like:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
    //Do ajax call here
});
```

Comment: How will that help reload the page *after* the ajax request completes?

Comment: If he were to use this approach, based on his stated intent, he would not put the ajax call there, he would put `window.location.reload();`